# angulardart: how StreamController works in the following example?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, dart, angular-dart

I am reading the [tutorial](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt6).

Example 1:

lib/src/hero_search_component.dart

```
class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  HeroSearchService _heroSearchService;
  Router _router;
  Stream<List<Hero>> heroes;
  StreamController<String> _searchTerms =
      new StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  HeroSearchComponent(this._heroSearchService, this._router) {}
  // Push a search term into the stream.
  void search(String term) => _searchTerms.add(term);
  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
    heroes = _searchTerms.stream
        .transform(debounce(new Duration(milliseconds: 300)))
        .distinct()
        .transform(switchMap((term) => term.isEmpty
            ? new Stream<List<Hero>>.fromIterable([<Hero>[]])
            : _heroSearchService.search(term).asStream()));
  }
}
```

lib/src/dashboard_component.html

```
<h3>Top Heroes</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes"  [routerLink]="['HeroDetail', {id: hero.id.toString()}]"  class="col-1-4">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<hero-search></hero-search>
```

I am confused how `StreamController` works. I have some questions:

1, In `void search(String term) => _searchTerms.add(term);`, a term is added to `_searchTerms`, which is a `StreamController`, not a `Stream`. Am I right?

2, The `heroes` in `<a *ngFor="let hero of heroes">` is `Stream<List<Hero>> heroes`?

3, `heroes` is initialized in `ngOnInit()` and a `stream` is assigned to `heroes`. I cannot understand how `heroes` are updated. Can anyone explain the process to me?

4, I am also reading the `Custom events` session in https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/template-syntax.
The codes are as following. (Example 2)

```
final _deleteRequest = new StreamController<Hero>();
@Output()
Stream<Hero> get deleteRequest => _deleteRequest.stream;

void delete() {
  _deleteRequest.add(hero);
}

<hero-detail (deleteRequest)="deleteHero($event)" [hero]="currentHero"></hero-detail>
```

In the above codes, `hero` is added to `_deleteRequest`. `deleteRequest` is the custom event, which is triggered and `$event` is passed to `deleteHero()` function. `$event` is just `hero`. Am I right? Can I consider `deleteRequest` to be a `event`?

5, In the first example, property `heroes` is connected to a stream. In the second example, a stream is `bind` to a event `deleteRequest`. Am I right?

Any hints welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some answers to your multipart question:

> 1. In `void search(String term) => _searchTerms.add(term);`, a term is added to `_searchTerms`, which is a `StreamController`, not a `Stream`. Am I right?

A `StreamController`, as the name implies, controls a stream. Values get fed into that stream when you call `StreamController.add()`.

Here is `lib/src/hero_search_component.html`:

```
<div id="search-component">
  <h4>Hero Search</h4>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box"
        (change)="search(searchBox.value)"
        (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
  <div>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async"
        (click)="gotoDetail(hero)" class="search-result" >
      {{hero.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice: `<input ... (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />`. After every key you type in the input search box (on keyup), the `HeroSearchComponent.search(String term)` method gets call, which in turn calls `StreamController.add()`. That is how values get pumped into the stream.

> 5, In the first example, property heroes is connected to a stream.

`heroes` is a stream obtained as follows: start with the stream from the controller but apply some transformations to it (debounce, etc).

> 4. ... `$event` is just `hero`. Am I right? Can I consider `deleteRequest` to be a `event`?

Yes the value of `$event` will be the `Hero` instance to be deleted. Yes, "deleteRequest" is the name of the custom even being fired.

Comment: `heroes` is assigned a stream in `ngOnInit()`. Any `hero` added by `_searchTerms.add(term)` will be fed into `heroes`?

Comment: Right, that's it!